# Coherent state of "generalized" annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, many-body, second-quantization, coherent-states

We all know that the coherent state $|\alpha \rangle=\sum_n \, \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}\,(a^{\dagger})^n \, |0\rangle  $ is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator: $a |\alpha\rangle = \alpha |\alpha \rangle $.

Lets say we have an operator which is a linear combination of permutations of creation and annihilation operators, but every summand has *exactly one annihilation more* then creation operators:

$$\tilde{a} \sim a+ a^{\dagger} a + a^{\dagger} a a^{\dagger} + a a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} +...$$

This operator will in total also only remove one particle from a quantum system, just like $a$.

Question: Can we always construct an eigenstate, similar to the coherent state, of this "generalized" annihilation operator?

$$\tilde{a} |\tilde{\alpha}\rangle = \tilde\alpha|\tilde \alpha\rangle$$

Idea:
The obvious guess is of course $\sum_n \, \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}\,(\tilde a^{\dagger})^n \, |0\rangle$. This should work iff $[\tilde a, \tilde a^{\dagger}] =1$.

I think we can WLOG assume that the operators are normal ordered because otherwise we just bring them in that form, with always retaining one annihilation more then creation. Thus we can write

$$ \tilde a = \sum_n \, C_{n}(a^{\dagger})^na^{n}a$$

Comment: When you say "all kinds of orders" do you mean "an arbitrary series of permutations" or "every possible permutation"? In the latter case I don't think your operator is well defined as I can write it the form $a\sum_i C_i n^i$ where $C_i\in\mathbb{Z} $ as it is a sum of commutators of $a$ and $a^\dagger $. If we let this act on a number state other than the vacuum we get an infinite series with integer terms, which is convergent iff there is some $N$ such that $C_i=0$ for all $i > N$, which I doubt is true. This operator, therefore, is only defined on the vaccum, where it is trivial.

Comment: Yes I mean an arbitrary series of permutations. There might be some set of coefficient such that we can find the eigenstate, and some for which we don't.

Comment: just note that $(a^{\dagger})^n a^n \neq (a^{\dagger}a)^n$ so the last transition in your last equation is wrong

Comment: You are perfectly right, I got ahead of myself!

Comment: Alternatively, your operator can always be brought into the form $\tilde a = f(\hat n)\hat a = \hat a g(\hat n)$, where $f(\hat n)$ and $g(\hat n)$ are arbitrary power series in $\hat n = \hat a^\dagger \hat a$. But I'm not sure whether that helps.